# Create a Dataset from String Spark Java (Without RDD)

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset

I need to create a `Dataset` from `String`. **Key is the String**

```
Header h = new Header();
                    h.setName(Key);
                    SQLContext sqlC = spark.sqlContext();     
                    Dataset<String> ds = sqlC.createDataset(Collections.singletonList(h), Encoders.STRING());
                    ds.show();
```

I need to write it into txt file(Is there one? I am using csv right now)

```
ds.write().format("com.databricks.spark.csv").mode("overwrite")
                .save(SomeLocation);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from documentation `df.write.text()`:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html#text-java.lang.String-

Comment: Thanks for that Lior, I am stuck at creating a dataset from a string

Comment: you're welcome. Seems to me that the reason you're stuck is that your collection is of `Header` objects. Not suitable for Encoders.STRING.
You can use `javaSparkContext.parallelize(Collections.singletonList(h))` to get a `JavaRDD<Header>`, and then use map function to convert it to `JavaRDD<String>`, and finally invoke `toDF()` to convert it to a dataframe. Or, from JavaRDD you can directly call https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDDLike.html#saveAsTextFile-java.lang.String-